# multiple Words to replace Dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I want to Dynamically replace the Words in a table column Since i dont know How Many Words Need to be Replaced

```
DECLARE @FormQuery NVARCHAR(max)='Case ', 
        @qry       NVARCHAR(max)=''; 

SELECT @FormQuery = +COALESCE(@FormQuery 
                              + 'When   ram.DynamicApplicableValueField Like ''%' 
                              + cmt.mastertype 
                              + '%'' Then   replace (ram.DynamicApplicableValueField ,''' 
                              + cmt.mastertype + ''',   rf.' 
                              + cmt.specialclausematchingcolumns + ') ', '') 
FROM   commonmastertypes cmt 
       JOIN (SELECT column_name 
             FROM   information_schema.columns 
             WHERE  table_name = 'ReeferDetails') spTable 
         ON cmt.specialclausematchingcolumns = spTable.column_name; 

SELECT @FormQuery
```

the O/P

```
 Case When ram.DynamicApplicableValueField Like '%@@Temp%' Then replace (ram.DynamicApplicableValueField ,'@@Temp', rf.Preset_Temperature) When ram.DynamicApplicableValueField Like '%@@Degree%' Then replace (ram.DynamicApplicableValueField ,'@@Degree', rf.Temp_UOM)
```

Expected Outcome

```
replace(replace(ram.DynamicApplicableValueField,'@@Temp',rf.Preset_Temperature),'@@Degree',rf.Temp_UOM)
```

Comment: Please **parametrise** your SQL and **quote** your object names. [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is not your friend.

Comment: `table_name = 'ReeferDetails'`... sounds like a dope application

Comment: Are your searched values always words without spaces?